# Customize wingpanel under Elementary OS

Tags: theme, elementary-os

Recently I have installed Elementary OS luna, which is based on Ubuntu. I want to customize the wingpanel to display the menu toolbar of the selected application.

This is my wingpanel: 
[image: what I got]

But I need it to look like this: 
[image: what I Want]

The File, Edit, Selection and other menus, and the Close, maximize and minimize icons are on the wingpanel.

Comment: The behaviour you describe is called “Global Menu”.

Answer (score 0):

Install **Mate Panel** on Elementary OS. [Here](http://goo.gl/En9Lef) precise tutorial how do it.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve global menus you can also use **Super Wingpanel** with **Elementary Tweaks.** 
And to get that first you'll need Elementary Tweaks. Open up the terminal and enter:
`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:versable/elementary-update`, `sudo apt-get update`, and finally `sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks`. Now goto `Applications > System Settings > Tweaks` and you'll see some new settings. Here you can add things such as the minimise button, change themes, etc. Once you've finished tinkering, type in the terminal `sudo apt-get install super-wingpanel`. Once you're done that, head over to `Applications > System Settings > Tweaks > Super Wingpanel`. If something doesn't work, just log out > log back in.